# Endless adding to list for merge sort in lisp

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, lisp, mergesort

This is what happens when i run my merge sort program in lisp.

(MSORT '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

"Stack overflow (deep)".

I'm pretty sure I constantly add to a list with my function, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
(defun fhl(l) 
    (progn
            (setf msize (mod (length l) 2));; mod for size even check
            (setf size (- (/ (length l) 2) 1));;size of list -1 because we start on pos 1 in list
            (setf f (list (car l)));;size of list -1 because we start on pos 1 in list

            (if (eq msize 1) (setf size (+(floor size)1)));;if mod = 1 list is odd - .5 to round to whole number + 1 for more even spread
            (dotimes (i size) 
                    (setf f (append f (list (nth (+ i 1) l)))));; add next element in list size times
     f));;return new list


(defun shl(l)
    (progn
            (setf msize (mod (length l) 2));; mod for size even check
            (setf size  (/ (length l) 2));;size of list -1 because we start on pos 1 in list
            (if (eq msize 1) (setf size (+(floor size) 1)));;if mod = 1 list is odd - .5 to round to whole number + 1 for more even spread

            (dotimes (i size) ;; loop for i items 
                    (setf l (cdr l)))
     l))


(defun msort(l) 
            (if (null l)
                    '();;empty list
            )
            (if (= (length l) 1) l);;1 item
                    (progn
                            (setf f (fhl l))
                            (setf s (shl l))
                            (merge 'list (msort f) (msort s) #'<)

                    )

)
```

Comment: A few style comments to improve your code. Use let instead of progn with setf. The first if statement in msort effectively does nothing. Try using nthcdr instead of dotimes & setf/cdr in shl.

Comment: Have you used trace to see how often your functions are being called and with what parameters?

Comment: You need to bind variables, not just assign to them, which is undefined behaviour and almost certainly catastrophically wrong in any recursive function.  It's unfortunate to say the least that Python and its ilk have caused binding and assignment to become confused in people's minds.

Comment: That `if` for an empty list won't cancel the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MSORT`-function has three body forms:

```
(defun msort (l)
  (if ...)
  (if ...)
  (progn ...))
```

Since a function returns the value from the last form, the two `IF`s don't actually do anything. Their values are just discarded, and the value from the `PROGN` is always returned.

To fix this, you should use `COND`. As people mentioned in the comments, you should also use `LET` to define local variables.

```
(defun msort (l)
  (cond ((null l) '())
        ((= (length l) 1) l)
        (t (let ((f (fhl l))
                 (s (shl l)))
             (merge 'list (msort f) (msort s) #'<)))))
```

Also, I must say that the functions `FHL` and `SHL` are pretty horribly named. A person reading the code should be able to understand what a function is used for without having to read its code. I assume they are acronyms for "first half list" and "second half list" respectively, so you should just use those names. In Common Lisp it's usually preferred to use full words for names (this goes for variables too).

Using two functions for the task of splitting a list is also bad, because the functions depend on the implementation details of the other regarding how to handle odd list length. It'd be better to combine them into one function. A simple implementation would be to just use a single `LOOP`:

```
(defun split-list (list)
  "Split LIST into two halves. Returns a cons containing the halves."
  (loop with mid-point = (floor (length list) 2)
        for element in list
        for i from 0
        if (< i mid-point) collect element into first-half
          else collect element into second-half
        finally (return (cons first-half
                              second-half))))
```

This returns the halves in a cons-cell. You can then use `DESTRUCTURING-BIND` to bind them into variables in `MSORT`. You could also use `VALUES` to return them as multiple values, and `MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND` to bind them, but I think a cons-cell (or a list) is better for this situation since it's unlikely anyone would ever want only one of the halves.

```
(defun mergesort (list)
  "Sort LIST using Mergesort-algorithm."
  (cond ((null list) '())
        ((= (length list) 1) list)
        (t (destructuring-bind (first-half . second-half) (split-list list)
             (merge 'list
                    (mergesort first-half)
                    (mergesort second-half)
                    #'<)))))
```